# How to filter null column in rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[25]
    @param1 int
AS
    SELECT c.Name, c.Age, c2.Name, c2.Country
    FROM Cus C 
    INNER JOIN Cus2 C2 ON c.id = c2.id
    WHERE c2.country is not null and c2.id = @param1
    ORDER BY c2.Country 

    RETURN 0
```

Above is my stored procedure.

What I want to happened is to filtered those rows who has a null column and only display those rows with a string value in that particular column.

I want it to display in RDLC. In my current stored procedure it will not filter out the null row's column.

Comment: `...with a string value in that particular column`. Which column?

Comment: @dotnetom The c2.Country.

Comment: The code above should work if any row in the c2.Country column has really a NULL value, of course, the code above will include all those rows that have an empty string in that column instead of NULL. Are you sure that the column Country has any NULL value?

Comment: You are probably mixing up NULLs and empty strings in your task definition. Empty string is not the same as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[25]
    @param1 int
AS
    SELECT c.Name, c.Age, c2.Name, c2.Country
    FROM Cus C 
    INNER JOIN Cus2 C2 ON c.id = c2.id
    WHERE (c2.Country <> '') and (c2.id = @param1)
    ORDER BY c2.Country 

RETURN 0
```

I just see the answer from another post. Thanks to those people who helped me.